# Is the trivial ring regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, regular-rings

In algebraic geometry if $f: X \to Y$ is locally of finite presentation (where $X, Y$ are schemes) then smoothness of $f$ implies that for all $y \in Y$ the "geometric fiber"
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}
\Spec{\overline{\kappa(y)}} \times_{Y} X$
is regular.

If $y$ has no preimage under $f$ then the geometric fiber should be empty, so it is the trivial ring $\{0\}$. Is this ring considered to be regular? I guess technically all of its localizations are regular local.

(In other words, must every smooth morphism of Schemes be surjective?)

Comment: A ring with one element can't be local.

Comment: @MattSamuel but it doesn't need to be local, right?

Comment: Are you saying it has no localizations?

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes. It has no localizations at prime ideals.

Comment: Is a smooth morphism from a finite scheme into an infinite scheme surjective?

Comment: No, smooth morphisms need not be surjective. Every open immersion is smooth. That is, if $X$ is a variety, $U\subset X$ an open set, then the inclusion $U\to X$ is smooth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty scheme is regular according to EGA IV.5.8.2. Accordingly, the zero ring is regular according to Bourbaki's AC.VIII.5 Exercice 6. (Of course, the point is that regularity is defined as some property *for every point* or *for every prime ideal,* resp.)

Comment: Dr. Rohrer, see comments here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3215492/690882